# What method is triggered on a custom CollectionViewCell when dequeued from a reusable Cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, reuseidentifier

I am dequeueing a reusable custom `ItemCollectionViewCell` as usual with the method from its parent ViewController

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ItemCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

but on my `ItemCollectionViewCell` I have the implemented the method `initWithFrame` which only gets called initially but not when a cell is dequeued for re-use.

What would be the method which gets triggered inside `ItemCollectionView` before being re-added to the queue after calling `[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]` on the parent view controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-[UICollectionReusableView prepareForReuse]` is the method. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionReusableView) is the documentation for the method.